# jQuery toggle function disorts text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some functions to toggle 2 parts of an HTML if I click the '*rejt*' button. Normally it looks like this:
[image: Normal]

But after using the button to toggle it back again, it gets disorted like this:
[image: Disorted]

Please help me fix this.

Code sample:

```js
function bottom() {
    var value = $('#toggle').attr('value');
    $('#bottomtext1').toggle('slow');
    $('#bottomtext2').toggle('slow');
    
    if (value == 'rejt'){
        $('toggle').attr('value', 'mutat');
    }
    else if (value == 'mutat') {
        $('toggle').attr('value', 'rejt');
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<id id="bottomtext1" style="display:none;">stuff1</id>

<input type="button" value="rejt" id="toggle" onclick="bottom();">

<id id="bottomtext2" style="display:none;">stuff2</id>
```

Comment: Would need a code sample to help. Looks like something is getting set as inline.

Comment: @AlexK. What do you want a screenshoot of?

Comment: @DJDavid98: We don't want a screenshot, we want to see the code.

Comment: It works when I change it to English :-)

Comment: @Rocket Because it's not the developement version, and does not include any of the code mentioned here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, what's with the `font` and `id` tags? Not sure what jQuery is going to do when toggling a tag it knows nothing about (`id`).

More importantly, these `id` tags are set to `display:inline-block` after the toggle, such as:

```
<id id="bottomtext2" style="display:inline-block" />
```

That element is adjacent to `<id id="bottomtext2" />`, also set to `inline-block`. This would explain the side-by-side display.

Broken Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T8aWV/1/
Fixed Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T8aWV/

Get rid of the `id` tags and make them `divs`. This fixed the problem for me.

See also: ["Periodic Table" of HTML 5 tags (and when to use them)](http://joshduck.com/periodic-table.html)

Comment: With some CSS I maged to make this work they way I wanted it to. Thak you!

Comment: Cool...make sure to validate your page as well, looks like there are some structural errors (easy to fix): http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhunpony.hu%2Ftoday%2Fdev%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0